# Perl INT handler and Bash STDERR redirection

Tags: perl, bash, signals

`foo.pl` catches `INT` signals i.e. `Ctrl-C.`

`foo.pl` works as expected.

Using `foo.pl 2>&1 | tee foo.log` signal catching seems not work.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say:

```
foo.pl 2>&1 | tee foo.log
```

then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> causes `tee` to terminate which sends `SIGPIPE` to the earlier process in the pipeline.

It seems that you want to catch `SIGPIPE` instead, but be warned about the [broken pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_pipe).

Comment: Hmmm ... I tried '$SIG{'PIPE'} = \&INT_handler;' without success. I want to mention that there is no problem with 'foo.pl | tee foo.log'. Only if I redirect STDERR, too.

Comment: If you're expecting output from your perl signal handler to end up in `foo.log`, that will never happen. `tee` terminates and stops writing to `foo.log` before the perl process receives a signal.

Comment: OK. It works. I was just anoyed that I got a prompt immediately although the INT hander takes some time to process. Seems to work somehow in the 'background' disconnected from the terminal.